# MySqlConnector:MySqlBulkLoader Class. Upload null data from csv to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, csv, null, mysql-connector

From MySqlConnector.MySQLBulkLoader Class
I want to convert csv to a MySQL table **keeping null values**.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

In csv file, save null data like **\N** (without "")

For example (.csv file)

```
"A US Equity","20220429","ACTV",\N,\N
```

When you upload file, MySQl will detect that's null value:

[image]

Config documentation:
https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkloadertype/